# Where should i save my tornado custom options

Tags: python, tornado

I am working on a python/tornado web application.

I have several options to save in my app.
Thoses options can by changed by the user, and those options will be access very often.
I have created an sqlite database but there is some disk operation and i am asking you what is the best location for those options.
Does tornado embed a feature for custom user options ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know tornado, but flask has a dictionary like top level object. I assume tornado has something similar. You could load all relevant data from the db to this dict at startup and save changes when you are shutting down. Even if it does not exist, it is quite easy to build, using some module level dict or a dedicated caching module

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is the `tornado.options` package, which does pretty much what you need. Keep in mind, however, that the values saved here are not persisted between requests; if you need that kind of functionality, you will have to implement an external persistence solution, which you already have done with SQLite.